# investigating the negative definiteness of a continuous but not differentiable function

Tags: analysis, multivariable-calculus

I'm stuck at showing whether the following function is negative definite. Consider the following function $V(x_{1},x_{2}):\mathbb{R}^{2}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$

$$
V(x_{1},x_{2})=-c_{3}l_{1}|x_{1}|^{1+\alpha_{1}}-(c_{2}l_{2}-c_{3})x_{2}^{2}+c_{1}x_{2}|x_{1}|^{\frac{1+\alpha_{1}}{2}}\mathrm{sgn}(x_{1})-c_{2}l_{1}|x_{1}|^{\alpha_{1}}\mathrm{sgn}(x_{1})|x_{2}|^{\frac{2}{1+\alpha_{1}}}\mathrm{sgn}(x_{2})-c_{3}l_{2}x_{1}|x_{2}|^{\frac{2\alpha_{1}}{1+\alpha_{1}}}\mathrm{sgn}(x_{2})
$$

where $l_{1}>0$, $l_{2}>0$ and $0<\alpha_{1}<1$ and $\mathrm{sgn}$ is the standard signum function. How can I determine for which values of $c_{1}$, $c_{2}$ and $c_{3}$, this function is negative definite, or such values doesn't exist and it is not negative definite at all? I thought since the first three terms can be collected in a quadratic form as
$$
V(x_{1},x_{2})=\begin{bmatrix}|x_{1}|^{\frac{1+\alpha_{1}}{2}}\mathrm{sgn}(x_{1})\\x_{2}\end{bmatrix}^{T}\begin{bmatrix}-c_{3}l_{1}&\frac{c_{1}}{2}\\\frac{c_{1}}{2}&-(c_{2}l_{2}-c_{3})\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}|x_{1}|^{\frac{1+\alpha_{1}}{2}}\mathrm{sgn}(x_{1})\\x_{2}\end{bmatrix}-c_{2}l_{1}|x_{1}|^{\alpha_{1}}\mathrm{sgn}(x_{1})|x_{2}|^{\frac{2}{1+\alpha_{1}}}\mathrm{sgn}(x_{2})-c_{3}l_{2}x_{1}|x_{2}|^{\frac{2\alpha_{1}}{1+\alpha_{1}}}\mathrm{sgn}(x_{2})
$$
can be helpful, however the last two terms are sign indefinite, so I couldn't continue. Since it is only continuous in all $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ but not differentiable at $(0,0)$, it doesn't seem likely to me that checking its gradient and Hessian can help either. I would greatly appreciate if someone can suggest me a method to investigate this. Thanks in advance.

Best regards,